# OneNote Screen Clipping behavior with keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2016

I'm having issues with the Send To OneNote tool with OneNote 2016 and Windows 10. The issue is that when using the keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>), it just automatically copies the screenshot to the clipboard. I think this started when I checked this box once before:

[image: Quick Filing Dialog (screenshot)]

I know you should be able to change this choice in the OneNote settings. But these settings seem to only change the behavior of the Send To OneNote icon in the taskbar, but *not the keyboard shortcut*. Is there any way to change this? Can I edit a registry value or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding this article by Microsoft unfortunately they changed the keyboard behavior, instead you can click on the taskbar shortcut and choose screen clipping from there, it will ask you for the location.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/why-doesn-t-the-screen-clipping-tool-work-anymore-311c21ff-68d9-4e2a-8769-ede9faafdb17

> Now, with the Windows 10 Creators Update, we have another change.
>   Windows+Shift+S still captures your screen, but instead of showing the
>   Select Location in OneNote dialog, the screen clipping is sent
>   immediately to your clipboard so that you can paste it into any
>   application, including OneNote.

Answer (score -1):

In my PC that setting is default. Why don't you use simple paste shortcut and paste it wherever you want(Ctrl V). I think it has become default after the creator's update 2017